# Javascript Button Error, Winter 16?

Tags: javascript, button, console

I have a button that needs to open in the Service Console, and here is my javascript, any ideas?  This is a new error and I am not sure how to handle, that is stopping a lot of activities

> Error
>
> Cannot read property
>           'getEnclosingPrimaryTabId of undefined

```
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/30.0/connection.js")} 
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/30.0/apex.js")} 

try { 
var query = "SELECT Id,Name,Contact__r.Name FROM TripProfile__c WHERE Trip__c = '{!Trip__c.Id}'"; 
var tripprofile = sforce.connection.query(query); 
var tripProfileArr = tripprofile.getArray("records"); 
if(typeof tripProfileArr === 'undefined' || tripProfileArr.length === 0 ) 
{ 
alert('There is no Trip Profile built yet'); 
}else if (typeof(srcUp) === 'function'){ 
var url = '/apex/tripprofile?tpid=' + tripProfileArr[0].Id; 
var callOpenSubtab = function callOpenSubtab(result) { 
sforce.console.openSubtab(result.id, '/apex/tripprofile?tpid=' + tripProfileArr[0].Id + '&isdtp=vw', true, 'TP - ' + tripProfileArr[0].Contact__r.Name); 
} 
sforce.console.getEnclosingPrimaryTabId(callOpenSubtab); 
} else { 
var url = '/apex/tripprofile?tpid=' + tripProfileArr[0].Id; 
window.open(url); 
} 
} catch (e) { 
alert(e); 
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`sforce.console` is in the Console Integration Toolkit's script along with that method you're trying to call: `getEnclosingPrimaryTabId`.

It looks like you're only loading the Ajax Toolkit. (`connection.js` & `apex.js`)

If you add the console integration toolkit to your button, you should be good to go.

```
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/support/console/34.0/integration.js")}
```

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_console.meta/api_console/